# What does policy_version_is_highest mean?

Tags: application-development

My app was just reviewed and the feedback comments mentioned "policy_version_is_highest". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

We always require the highest security policy version. By updating the value to the highest available (which also is the current) version, the app developer also acknowledges the newest security policy.